# In ASP.Net Core, is it possible to start streaming JSON results?

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, postgresql, asp.net-web-api

I am using ASP.Net Core WebAPI.

I have a method that retrieves 10000 results from the database at a time, but I notice that it takes 1.17s to "wait" and 0.3s for the actual transfer (based on Chrome's network graph).

With the results from the database (postgres) are iterated through the DataReader and converted into a struct, added to a list, and ultimately returned as a JsonResult.

I do not know what to expect exactly for options, but I would like to be able to start returning as soon as possible to make the total request lower. I am also doing this for the first time on this platform, so I may not be doing things the best way.

```
    [HttpGet("{turbine:int}")]
    public IActionResult GetBearingTemperature(int turbine)
    {
        using (var connection = Database.GetConnection())
        {
            connection.Open();

            int? page = GetPage();

            var command = connection.CreateCommand();

            if (page.HasValue)
            {
                command.CommandText = @"select turbine, timestamp, mainbearingtemperature from readings where turbine = :turbine limit 10000 offset :offset;";
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("offset", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer, page.Value * 10000);
            } else
            {
                command.CommandText = @"select turbine, timestamp, mainbearingtemperature from readings where turbine = :turbine limit 10000;";
            }

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("turbine", NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Integer, 4, turbine);                

            var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            var collection = new List<BearingTemperature>();

            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                var bt = new BearingTemperature();

                while (reader.Read())
                {                        
                    bt.Time = reader.GetDateTime(1);
                    bt.Turbine = reader.GetInt32(0);
                    bt.Value = reader.GetDouble(2);

                    collection.Add(bt);
                }

                return new JsonResult(collection);
            }
            else
            {
                return new EmptyResult();
            }

        }
    }

    private int? GetPage()
    {
        if (Request.Query.ContainsKey("page"))
        {
            return int.Parse(Request.Query["page"]);
        }
        else return null;

    }

    struct BearingTemperature
    {
        public int Turbine;
        public DateTime Time;
        public double Value;
    }
```

Comment: 1.17s to "wait" and 0.3s for the actual transfer of 10,000 records seems pretty good to me.  I suspect that most of that time is being spent executing the SQL query, and that streaming will make no difference at all.

Comment: I just got some results from logging:
Executing Query @ 538
Iterating @ 565
Response @ 591

These results show milliseconds. It think I am misunderstanding where the delay comes from - it doesn't seem to be in the method itself. This is all on local host - so what is causing the wait?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considering that your database is going to execute the query and return the entire result set, it's not possible for you to stream a partial result set (though you can google streaming database for other offerings).  What you could do instead is use a paging technique combined with ajax to retrieve slices of the total result set and compose them together on the client to keep the responsiveness high and create the illusion of streaming query results.

You'll want to look at `OFFSET` and `LIMIT` clauses

On your api, you'd include parameters for offset and limit to allow the client to step through and retrieve the result set in whatever size chunks it wants, you can play with it to determine what seems responsive enough.  Then on your client, you'll need a loop over an ajax call to your api, probably using jquery, and keep looping page after page adding the results to the bound collection on the client or create ui elements, or whatever, until the results come back empty.

Alternatively, if showing the whole 10k records at once isn't necessary, you could simply page the results and provide an interface to step through the pages.  One that I've used for such a purpose is from Sakura on git hub: [PagedList](https://github.com/sgjsakura/AspNetCore)

Comment: My SQL already uses OFFSET and LIMIT. The way I have setup my api, it works with /api/mbt/{id}  with a query section that would have ?page={num}  where num would end up being multiplied by 10000. 

Eventually, the front end will be using AJAX, and probably doing aggregations - if it was not possible to do them on the database.

Comment: Ah, I see - didn't scroll over before on your sql.  Well, those are the limitations.  The wait is just the time it takes for the sql to execute, transfer the data from sql server to your controller, iterate over the results and compose the return.  So, if you want to shorten that time, you can reduce the LIMIT and pass smaller chunks between controller and browser.  The client side code to control the data coming back is where the control is.  Alternatively, look at `PushStreamContent`:  https://weblogs.asp.net/andresv/asynchronous-streaming-in-asp-net-webapi

Answer (score 7):

So I know this question is old, but this is very much possible in Asp.Net Core 2.2 (probably even from earlier versions, ever since `IEnumerable<T>` was supported as a return result on an action).

While I'm not entirely familiar with postgres and DataReader, the functionality is there to get it streaming the result to the client. Appending to a list, and returning the result in its entirety takes up a lot of memory depending on the size of the result, and streaming helps us avoid that.

Here is an example of an action, that returns an `IEnumerable<string>` that is streamed to the client (it is sent in chunks until everything has been delivered using the `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` header).

```cs
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
    return GetStringsFor(10000);
}

private static readonly Random random = new Random();
private IEnumerable<string> GetStringsFor(int amount)
{
    const string chars = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";
    while (amount-- > 0)
    {
        yield return new string(Enumerable.Repeat(chars, random.Next(1000)).Select(s => s[random.Next(s.Length)]).ToArray());
    }
}
```

This will ensure that not everything is loaded into memory, but sent on demand. You would be able to implement something similar in your case when you're reading to data into memory, because that is one time where the system could just start sending the result instead.

```cs
private IEnumerable<BearingTemperature> ReadTemperatures(SqlDataReader reader)
{
    if (reader.HasRows)
    {
        var bt = new BearingTemperature();

        while (reader.Read())
        {
            bt.Time = reader.GetDateTime(1);
            bt.Turbine = reader.GetInt32(0);
            bt.Value = reader.GetDouble(2);

            yield return bt;
        }
    }

    yield break;
}

[HttpGet("{turbine:int}")]
public IEnumerable<BearingTemperature> GetBearingTemperature(int turbine)
{
    using (var connection = Database.GetConnection())
    {
        <snip>

        var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
        return ReadTemperatures(reader);
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work from ASP.NET Core 3.0+.

`ASP.NET Core 3.0 and later buffers the result of the following action before providing it to the serializer.`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-3.1. 

I am still trying to find a workaround.

Comment: @extremeandy isn't the change in the link you posted? They moved it to IAsyncEnumerable<T>, so the underlying fetching of data has to be async'ed.

Comment: The link posted also says `MVC automatically buffers any concrete type that implements IAsyncEnumerable<T>`. I've tried even with `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` and observed that the memory consumption of the process keeps growing, it doesn't seem to be streaming at all but just buffering up all the results til enumeration is complete.

See also: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/30981